# Android - Google Drive SDK - Completion events

Tags: android, events, google-drive-api

I am new to the Android Google Drive SDK, so I have implemented a service to receive completion events to save the `DriveId` of the files I create in the user's Drive once they're uploaded.

Here it's the code I use to upload the file, note that I delete the original file if it was requested after it has been put into the google drive sdk request:

```
ExecutionOptions executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions.Builder()
            .setNotifyOnCompletion(true)
            .setTrackingTag(documentFileId)
            .build();

driveFileResult.getDriveFile()
         .open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_WRITE, null)
         .setResultCallback(result -> {

            DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
            driveContents.commit(mGoogleApiClient, null, executionOptions)
                    .setResultCallback(status -> {
                        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                            // handle bad status
                            return;
                        }

                        // Once the file has been passed to google drive it should be deleted
                        // if the delete extra parameter was passed
                        if (isFileDeletable && file != null) {
                            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                        }
                        hideNotification();
                    });
        });
```

Here the code of the service of the completion event.

```
public class UploadCompletionService extends DriveEventService {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(CompletionEvent completionEvent) {
        String driveId = completionEvent.getDriveId().getResourceId();
        // THE LOGIC GOES HERE
        completionEvent.dismiss();
    }
}
```

So the problem is the frequency, I upload one file and then immediately I get the event, then I create a second file and the event takes a little longer to retrieve the success, then two or more files later the event is not called anymore.

I wonder if the problem has to do with deleting the file when I get the result callback from the drive contents, or if it's necessary I make sure of closing or freeing resource I am not having in count, or if it is not a good idea to delete the local file before I have gotten a completion event. What is it I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try double checking how your code works, specially how your code must behave in line with the [Lifecycle of a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files#lifecycle_of_a_drive_file). In the document about Working with File Contents, it discuss how to read a file, how to read it from input stream and **closing the file content**. Check how you close the file content; proper **closing of file contents when you're done using them, in order to free related resources**. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think I have tried everything that is in there, even though I am not sure of what is happening now. I have worked with the Api for a week so I committed a lot of mistakes while learning to the point of crashing of my personal device Play Store services. I had to  restore the defaults and then everything is working all right. The app has been working fine again so I suppose it is fixed. I am not sure if it is fixed for real, and this is the reason I have not closed this question yet since there may be something I still ignore. Thank you anyways for the advice.

Comment: I'm currently working on this too, had mixed results - sometimes I get an instant completion event others nothing.  For me this needs to work perfectly every time not intermittently so I will let you know my findings!